# No puedo hacer que la calculadora de IMC funcione. Siempre me da 0.00 el resultado

Tags: javascript, funciones

El código donde está la calculadora no me funciona, se muestra todo lo demás pero la operación siempre me da 0.00 ponga los datos númericos que ponga, siempre el mismo resultado.
Tampoco me aparece que haya un error, por eso no sé donde está el error y como lo puedo solucionar.

```js
alert("Bienvenido a la calculadora de IMC");

const usuarioAutorizado = "Daniela";
const contraseniaAutorizada = "4607";
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

   let usuario = prompt("Ingrese su usuario: ");
   let contrasenia = prompt("Ingrese su contraseña: ");

   if (usuario === usuarioAutorizado && contrasenia === contraseniaAutorizada) {
      alert("Acceso concedido " + usuario);
      break;

   } else {
      alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecta, tecleá bien amigoo");
   }
}

let peso = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese su peso: "));
let estatura = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese su estatura: "));

function calcularImc() {

   let clasificacion;

   let imc = (peso / (estatura ** 2));

   if (imc < 18.5) {
      clasificacion = "peso inferior al normal"
   } else if (imc >= 18.5 && imc < 24.9) {
      clasificacion = "peso normal";
   } else if (imc >= 24.9 && imc < 25) {
      clasificacion = "peso superior al normal";
   } else {
      clasificacion = "obesidad";
   }
   let respuesta = "El indice de masa corporal es de: " + (imc.toFixed(2)) +
                   " y tu tienes " + clasificacion;
   alert(respuesta);
}
```

Comment: Considera el caso en que el usuario presiona el botón **Cancelar**. No creo que quiera seguir intentando iniciar sesión. Cuando se presiona ese botón, el prompt devuelve [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular el IMC se debe obtener tanto el **peso** como la **altura** en valores **decimales**, y al estar utilizando `parseInt()` estás dejando estos valores como enteros, es decir, que si tienes un peso de **75,50kg** y una altura de **1,70m**, tus variables estarán almacenando solo la parte entera, osea **75kg** y **1m**. Si bien en el peso no es tan necesaria la parte decimal ya que no influirá tanto en el valor final, la altura si, así que procura eliminar `parseInt()` o cambiarlos por `parseFloat()`. Y no te olvides de introducir los valores con puntos y no con comas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya me di cuenta donde estaba el error y era en la misma fórmula ya que estaba poniendo los datos de la altura en cm.  Para aclarar: pongo parseInt() para que me devuelva un número y no un string. Lo de los decimales no hace falta ya que en el resultado lo ajuste con un toFixed(2).